# How far can one event go and how do I listen for it?

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling, addeventlistener, dispatchevent

I have code in a flex component that I want to listen for an event, the source of the event is a custom class that's being run by another class that's being run by another class etc etc. I was under the impression that an event would pass throughout the whole application, so I was hoping if I dispatched the custom event in the class like so..

```
    private function finishEvent():void {
        var evt:EventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher;
        var finished:Event = new Event("finishedInterpret");
        evt.dispatchEvent(finished);
    }
```

then I could just grab it in my component like this:

```
public function interpret(data:Array):void {
    addEventListener("finishedInterpret", applyInferences);
    db.executeBatch();
}
```

the event gets fired basically when the executeBatch is finished, and the finishEvent is being called, but I'm the listener isn't getting anything. I tried setting it to db.addEventListener, but that had now effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that events are supposed to happen is that an object dispatches events, and consumers of those events listen for events *from that object*.  Unless you have a global event dispatcher (not typical), there is no application-wide event dispatching.

I find this to be the best pattern to use: child components dispatch events, and the owner of those children listen for their events.  For example:

```
child.addEventListener("finishedInterpret", applyInferences);
```

As is, your code is listening for events *from itself*.

Comment: ah i see. unfortunately the component in the class that I'm using that's determining things are finished is pretty buried in several levels of class calls.. so I'd basically have to pass an event up each level then I guess.. hrmph was hoping not to have to heavily modify that code

Comment: You could use event bubbling.  That would allow the event to propagate through multiple layers to the first listening ancestor in the display tree.

Comment: ah.. i had thought that was enabled by default. when i try to set bubbles to true it is a read-only property

Comment: Is this a custom event or built-in event?  You should add a custom event class and pass the `bubbles` parameter to the constructor of `Event`.  You can only make it a bubbling event at construction time.

Comment: ah it was a custom event but not its own class.. i see now. thanks!

Comment: I have tried with a custom event class that has bubbles to true but it's not getting it. much unfortunate.

Comment: Bubbling only works through display objects on the stage, from children to parents upwards. If an object is not added to the stage, events will not bubble through it.